# Set two different environments in a dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have implemented a `dll` for consuming an API. It's working properlyn but now I have to allow user to consume the `dev` and `production` API's (we have separate environments for dev and production). I don´t know how to do it.

I can implement a `switch` and allow the user to set production or dev and just change the path, but I'm guessing this is bad practice.

Actually, I have a path stored in `app.config`. Any suggestions on how to implement this or is the only way to send the user two `dll`'s, one for production and one for dev?

Comment: Why can't the user set a flag in their `app.config` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be:

- to store the path in app.config
- create environment specific transforms for the config file
- transform the config file during deployments

Sample config:

```
<add key="apiUrl" value="http://localhost/myapi" />
```

And corresponding transform file

```
<add key="apiUrl" value="http://devhost/myapi" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

You can use plugins like [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to do the transformation.

Alternatively, you can use [MSBuild tasks](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/09/14/using-custom-webconfig-transformations-in-msbuild) to do the transformation as well:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
                        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
<Target Name="TransformWebConfig">
    <TransformXml Source="C:\myapp\app.config"
                  Transform="C:\myapp\app.dev.config"
                  Destination="C:\myapp\bin\<web.config or in case of exe, product.exe.config>"
                  StackTrace="true" />
</Target>
```

**Note:** DLL files in .Net cannot have config files. So I'm assuming you're referring to the exe or web.config of your product.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional compilation could be an option for this.

It's not too hard to set up. A good article is:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451734/Visual-Studio-Use-Conditional-Compilation-to-Contr